# WSREP: failed to report last committed and stop

Tags: mariadb, clustering, galera

I have galera cluster and I have 4 nodes. I'm importing some data. however one node gives error. Warning. The warning is;

```
warning WSREP: Failed to report last committed 59102, -q (interrupted system call) 
mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
mysqld_safe WSREP: not restarting wsrep node automatically
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

What is that error? How can I solve this? This node shouldn't stop, not mysql service stopped in that error. Thanks

Comment: Are all four nodes master nodes? As far as I'm aware, due to its transactional nature, you must always have an odd number of master nodes to handle transaction clashes.

Answer (score 2):

> warning WSREP: Failed to report last committed

This is just a warning, and in itself isn't a cause for concern. I think it's unlikely that this caused the node to stop. See also [Percona's blog post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/27/galera-error-failed-to-report-last-committed-interrupted-system-call/) about it.

And then:

> mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0

Again, according to [Percona (Support)](https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtradb-cluster/13923-percona-cluster-node-goes-down?p=14098#post14098):

> Your mysqld process was killed, most likely by OOMkiller. Check the system log. Joining node will refuse to accept connections until it synchronizes with cluster.